# Dynamically Moving dependencies in java

Tags: java, jar, package, noclassdeffounderror

I have a file Main.jar (Swings App) which is executable jar. This Jar has a dependency of Code.jar which depends on the some environment. After packaging it the file structure is like this:

```
  Main.jar
  lib
   |_____Code.jar
```

Now in Main.jar there is a logic which as per environment requirement Updating Code.jar and replacing the Code.jar file in lib folder(in the first screen of my program). I have verified the Manifest file of Jar.

The classes in Code.jar file I need at third screen of my main program.

Problems:

1. I am not able to delete the Code.jar file already present in the folder. It might be because of dependency So i removed it using cmd before starting program.

   Is there any way by which i can delete file inside code instead of using cmd
2. When I remove the jar file using cmd, and move a new Code.jar in the lib folder, it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the classes present in the Code.jar. Even if the Code.jar is present in lib folder.

   What is reason of this error?

Comment: what do you mean by "using cmd"? You need to show us in high level how you have done the work so we can validate your approach

Comment: i have created a cmd file which first delete the code.jar file and then do `java -jar Main.jar`